# react-slick not working on the wordpress frontend when added to block

Tags: wordpress, gutenberg-blocks

I am trying to make a slick slider wordpress block.
it is working fine in the editor panel. but not on the frontend.
Also Getting error when including Slider component to save.js file and after that editor js gets blank too.
Please help.
Here is my Code

```
edit.js
_____
import { useBlockProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import Slider from "react-slick";
export default function Edit({attributes, setAttributes}) {
    const {Settings, slides} = attributes
    // console.log(attributes)

    // Settings
    // slides

    return (
        <div { ...useBlockProps() }>
            <p>Heading</p>
            <Slider {...Settings}>
                <div>
                    <h3>1</h3>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h3>2</h3>
                </div>
            </Slider>
        </div>
    );
}

Save.js
______

import Slider from "react-slick";
import { useBlockProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';

export default function Save({attributes}) {

    const {Settings, slides} = attributes
    console.log(Settings)
    const blockProps = useBlockProps.save()
    return (

        <div {...blockProps}>
            <div className="slider-container">
            <Slider {...Settings}>
                <div>
                    <h3>1</h3>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h3>2</h3>
                </div>
            </Slider>
            </div>
        </div>

    );
}
```

just want to have a simple working slick slider on wordpress block.